# equals() method of Object class

Tags: java, oop, jls

I was reading [`JLS, The Class Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2)  and according to it

```
The method equals defines a notion of object equality, which is based on value, 
not reference, comparison.
```

but when I opened the Declaration of `equals` method of `Object` class, which is:

```
public boolean equals (Object o) {
    return this == o;
}
```

But here, reference is checked with `Reference equality operator(==)`, how this Declaration is matching the specification?

Comment: What are the values in an Object? It has no attributes to be compared,so the object itself is the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [javadoc for `Object`'s `.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> The equals method for class Object implements **the most discriminating possible equivalence relation** on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

Which means, if you don't override it in your class, this is what you get.

The JLS is still right about what it says; however it is up to implementations to define their own `.equals()` contract.

(and of course, if you override `.equals()`, you should override [`.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) as well)

Comment: please elaborate why I need to override `.hashCode()` if I override `.equals()`

Comment: @Vishrant Because if a.equals(b) then is mandatory that a.hashCode()==b.hashCode() or you'll have a lot of problems using collections, for example

Comment: also according to `javadoc` it is `this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).`  but when I was reading JLS http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2 it is written comparison is based on `value, 
not reference, comparison.`

Comment: @Vishrant read the javadoc again, in particular "defines the most discriminating equivalence relation" part

Comment: @Vishrant if you use a `HashSet` and forget to override `.hashCode()`, two values which are `.equals()` could be duplicated in the set, and this would violate `Set`'s contract (since `HashSet` defines equivalence via `.equals()`)

Comment: @Vishrant HashMap implementation uses the hashCode value to allocate and search elements.

Comment: @Vishrant rule of thumb: override both, always; it will avoid nasty surprises for you _and_ your users (maybe _you_ will never use your objects in `Hash*`s, but you cannot guarantee this of your users)